# What is the difference between passing data in this way to properties in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have seen these ways to pass data to properties:

```
 <Header headerText={'Authentication'} />     

 <Header headerText="Authentication" />
```

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass `string` as prop then you can enclose it with `''` or `""`.

If you want to pass an object, boolean, integer, float, variable etc., then you can use the curly brace `{}`

Example:

```
<Header headerText={'Authentication'} />  

 <Header headerText={"Authentication"} />   

 <Header headerText="Authentication" />

<Header headerText='Authentication' />
```

All the above are treated as strings.

If you want to pass any other type as props then you can use `{}`

Example:

passing variable as prop

```
const auth = Authentication
<Header headerText={auth} />
```

passing boolean as prop

```
<Header headerText={false} />
<Header headerText={true} />
```

passing integer or float as prop

```
<Header headerText={1} />
<Header headerText={1.0} />
```

Answer (score 1):

No difference in the result for the example you provided. The only difference is that syntactically the first can accept a variable if needed, while the second will always coerce to a string.

So this is possible with the first, not with the second:

```
var auth = 'Authentication'
<Header headerText={auth} />
```